# Rails ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError Editing multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, activemodel

I followed Railscast Episode 165 (revised) to the tee on how to edit and Update multiple records in one form.  But when I submit my form to edit multiple records at the same time, I get:

`ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`

For this line:

`product.update_attributes(params[:product].reject { |k,v| v.blank? })`

Params:

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"g5C2siF5GcWfPxhph4utWn8JBs2JXEpIUBDO6OlFyQQ=",
 "product_ids"=>["11142",
 "11143"],
 "product"=>{"user_id"=>"",
 "allow_multi_users"=>"true",
 "state_id"=>"",
 "site"=>"",
 "department"=>"",
 "room"=>"",
 "asset_type_id"=>"",
 "asset_model_id"=>"",
 "sync_with_jss"=>"",
 "carrier_id"=>"",
 "mobile_contract_req_date"=>"",
 "mobile_contract_end_date"=>"",
 "mobile_international_plan"=>"",
 "mobile_tethering"=>"",
 "mobile_account"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Update"}`
```

Normally, I would think this is because I have not permitted an attribute in strong parameters. But this isn't a attribute, it's the params for the form that hold all the values.

This is for my Products.rb model so shouldn't it already accept **params[:product]**?

**products_controller.rb**

```
private  
  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:mobile_account, :mobile_international_plan, :mobile_tethering, :mobile_contract_end_date.. )
  end
```

Using Rails 4.0.0

Comment: please try adding the value of `puts params[:product]` to your question.

Comment: I've added the params output during the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
def update
  ...
  product.update_attributes(product_params)
  ...
end

private

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:mobile_account, :mobile_international_plan, :mobile_tethering, :mobile_contract_end_date.. )
  end
```

The list of fields are the fields you expect your user send to update or create.

You can find more information [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)

The error ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError is raised when you try to update a model with a params object with params that don't were permited, all the fields present at the form, must be permited to update the record.

Comment: Then you must call update_attributes with product_params

Comment: Wow. Of course! That makes perfect sense and I didn't see it.  Thank you.